# Is there a way to add noises that don't have an onomatopoeia?

Tags: dialogue

> "Brrrrrr, it's cold, brrrrr!" said Emanuel
>
> "teeth grinding noise" it's cold, teeth grinding noise" said
> Emanuel.

Is there a way to add noises that don't have an onomatopoeia? I can't think of a way to express the sound inside quotes. Is there a way to do this? How is this usually done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Describe the actions creating the sound

Using onomatopoeia in dialogue is a stylistic choice, however there isn't a perfect one for every situation. Trying to invent them, or force an obscure one into your dialog will distract the reader and break your narrative flow.

Instead you want to describe the scene, show the reader what is happening to create the sound and they will imagine it. So in your case the example becomes:

> "It's freezing." Emanuel muttered, jaw clenched, teeth grinding in response to the chill.

Alternatively you could describe the sound itself:

> "It's... cold..." Emanuel's voice momentarily silenced the grating squeak of his teeth grinding together.

How you write it is a stylist choice and you may like to write it in several different ways. Read the section aloud to see which is the least jarring and fits with the narrative flow, while conveying the effect you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something along the lines of: "'It's so cold. So cold.' Emanuel said, grinding his teeth while he did so. He rubbed his hands together to try and get some warmth, although it barely worked."

The goal is to describe what someone watching (either omnipresently, as a 'bystander', or as a character) would think when watching. The person probably wouldn't say 'Brrrr.' They would instead see and hear Emanuel grinding his teeth, shivering, etc.

And the lack of onomatopoeia also comes back to the good old 'Show, don't tell." By listing the sounds, you're telling what they sound like. By saying what causes it, you're showing what happened.

As for the repetition, it just sounded more natural. Honestly, flow is a big part of writing, too, in my eyes.

Comment: Try adding more detail and depth into your answer.

Comment: @Alexandrang Okay, I'll add some of my thought process.